# While loop inside if-statement with the same condition inside?

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop

One very experienced programmer wrote something like this:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Fraction
{
 float nominator;
 float denominator;

void load()
{
 cin>>nominator; cin>>denominator;
 if(denominator==0)
        {
          while(denominator==0)
          { 
            cout<<"denominator can not be equal 0!"<<endl;
            cin>>denominator;
          }
        }
}
};
```

I have no idea why there is an if statement. Is it really necessary?

Comment: No, it's not necessary.

Comment: @Bartek Węgrzyn Why do you have decided that the code is written by a very experienced programmer ?:)

Comment: usually ide gives a warning when == op used to compare float and 0. strange code anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this particular example,

```
while(denominator==0)
{ 
  cout<<"denominator can not be equal 0!"<<endl;
  cin>>denominator;
}
```

would be exactly equivalent.

In the context you provided, nothing can tell us why someone would nest that loop in an useless `if`, but one could come up with explanations. In earlier version of that code, something could have been present inside the `if` block that changed the behavior of the program/function.

It also could be an innocent error.

Stroustrup's cat might have walked on their keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it really necessary?

No, it is not necessary.

The shown snippet is equivalent to a program where the if statement is replaced with the contained loop statement.

Answer (score 0):

From this code:

```
 if(denominator==0)
    {
      while(denominator==0)
      { 
        cout<<"denominator can not be equal 0!"<<endl;
        cin>>denominator;
      }
    }
```

I think `if` is only used for a teaching purpose to simply show that how flow will go to `while` after checking **if** condition. And how `while loop` will work further.

But **if** is not really required here.
This code do the same:

```
while(denominator==0)
{ 
  cout<<"denominator can not be equal 0!"<<endl;
  cin>>denominator;
}
```